# awk/sed reading line by line from a file and replace a substring in each line

Tags: awk, sed

```
while read line
do
//Each line is a file name
//After reading each line i want to replace substring .json with .jpeg and use it in the below cp command.
 cp /mnt/ftp/xml/dd/ingest/new/processed/$line /mnt/ftp/xml/dd/ingest/JnJ-redo1
done < error_files.txt
```

Comment: You need to take the value of `line` and replace `.json` with `.jpeg` and then use that where you currently have `$line` or somewhere else? Is the value of `$line` just the filename you need?

Comment: Exactly. I wan to use the replaced .jpeg line in $line. $line is just a file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to do what you want here.

```
while read line
do
    cp /mnt/ftp/xml/dd/ingest/new/processed/"${line/.json/.jpeg}" /mnt/ftp/xml/dd/ingest/JnJ-redo1
done < error_files.txt
```